# SQL Server SUM/Group/Window Function

Tags: sql-server, group-by, sum, window-functions

Good day,
I have a table as follows.

[image: Before Adding New Column]

What I would love to do is add a new Column that will tabulate/summarize (anyway possible) called "New Net" by CovID/PolicyNo/CovYear/Positive(Negative) values.

In the example below the new  column would look like this.
In short, what we are trying to do is SumUp all the Values in that group and only place that total in the first row of that group and zero out all the others.  Any help/pointers would be appreciated with this.  I have tried SQL Server Window Functions, standard SUM/GROUP.

[image]

Comment: it helps to show us what you tried. However, lookup GROUP BY Grouping sets and/or the ROLLUP/CUBE functions. They do something similar.

Comment: Aren't all of the extra rows a bit redundant? You could get all of the pertinent information with a `SELECT DISTINCT` query.

Comment: If you are on 2012+ you should look at the LEAD/LAG functions.

Comment: Joe - I don't have control over the table that is currently there.  I can't delete/update the "Net" column.  Jeremy - Thanks for pointing me to Rollup command.  Never heard of it.

Comment: by the way, here are the things i tried -- ,                                            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Coverage_CoverageID-Certificate_CertificateID-CoverageInYear ORDER BY CoverageInYear) AS NewNet

Comment: @GeorgeEivaz check out https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522495(v=sql.105).aspx It compares grouping sets, rollup and cube functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should meet ypur expectations:

```
SELECT  PolicyNo ,
        CovID , 
        CovYear ,
        p ,
        net, 
        CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY CovID, PolicyNo, CovYear, net ORDER BY PolicyNo) = 1 THEN net ELSE 0 END AS NewNet
FROM    dbo.test1;
```